# Comment out a block of code in Apache Web Server?

Tags: macos, apache

Is there a way to comment out blocks of code in the Apache httpd.conf file? I know if you add the # sign it would comment out that directive or module. I'm testing a few things out and I want to comment out a section without having to delete each and every # sign, is this possible? I am using Apache version 2.2 on Mac OSX 9 by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I found a pretty cool way to comment out a block of code by wrapping the content you want ignored with a made up IfDefine directive.
For example:

```
<IfDefine IgnoreFollowing>
<Files private.html>
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 </Files>
</IfDefine>
```

The Files directive will be ignored because IgnoreFollowing is a made up parameter that would never test to true. If you wanted the Files directive to be executed just simply remove the IFDefine.

Answer (score 1):

backup the file `cp httpd.conf httpd.conf.bak`, edit the httpd.conf file, then restart apache.

if you know the lines you want to comment you can do something like this:

```
for l in {25..50}; do sed -i '' "${l} s/^/#/" httpd.conf; done
```

When using sed to change a file on osx you need to use the `-i ''` option. However, it would probably be quicker to open the file in an editor and make the changes. Many editors have keyboard shortcuts for un/commenting blocks of code. I know Sublime and Eclipse use cmd+/ as the shortcut for commenting lines.

Comment: +1 for your time thanks, also check out my answer I found, pretty cool stuff.